# Data and information security aboard the ISS in terms of public photos?

Tags: iss, security, public-involvement

I was looking through a couple posts that had on-board pictures of the ISS and noticed something almost immediately:

[image: Laptop screens.]

They have information (which could be sensitive) shown on the laptops:

[image: Closeup screens.]

While blurry, it doesn't seem to be being actively blurred out; rather, just because it's not in focus, it's hard to read. I'd imagine there are shots where things could be read. Is there anything they do actively to prevent ISS data from being leaked to the public through photos such as this? From the photos I've seen they don't even lock the laptops (I've not seen any with the windows lock screen).

---

Example of a blurred screen from @uhoh:

> for example 00:14 upper right hand corner, 2nd screen from the right?
>   [youtu.be/CTCq-M2Tr50](https://youtu.be/CTCq-M2Tr50) [i.stack.imgur.com/0Zul5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zul5.png) The video addresses
>   your topic nicely, if obliquely.

I believe I can edit the question to ask, when and what are they concerned with blurring out? It seems inconsistent. Who makes the call that the data is sensitive enough for a blur?

Comment: The laptops are their interface with much of the onboard systems. Lock screens seem antithetical to that goal. And I'm scratching my head wondering just how much sensitive info they display? I do not have any sources to provide an answer, but my hunch is this is a complete non-issue. The most sensitive thing dealt with on those screens may be a password, and they are obscured by standard typically.

Comment: @uhoh the lady watching youtube on her laptop? Ohhhh the blurred-out screen there! Nice one. Yeah, something like that. I want to know under what scenario that's deemed necessary-- who's deciding when to do that?

Comment: for example `00:14` upper right hand corner, 2nd screen from the right? https://youtu.be/CTCq-M2Tr50  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zul5.png The video addresses your topic nicely, if obliquely.

Comment: @Saiboogu I'm thinking more along the lines of emails, confidential communications, or information about things that haven't been publicly published (such as the drill hole on the ISS). I honestly didn't even think about uhoh's scenario, satellite data and information.

Comment: and those laptops are all turned to face the camera too

Comment: There's a team of people that screens every image and video that come down for sensitive information. Anything in those photos was deemed to be acceptable for public viewing.

Comment: To add to what @doresoom said: hundreds to thousands of images are downlinked every day. Those images that are public have been carefully screened.

Comment: BTW, the experiment Jeff Williams is performing in the photo is the SPHERES Zero Robotics competition, which is a middle and high school coding and robotics competition. He's got the test plan up on the screen, which is definitely not sensitive information.